# How to stop tweets streaming?

Tags: python, bottle, tweepy, sentiment-analysis, textblob

It seems to ignore the `if self.i >5:` statement (I have removed my keys). The tweets should stop streaming after a few tweets but continuously stream until the program has been stopped. I have tried `sys.exit()` and return worked at the end.

```
from bottle import route, default_app, get, post, request, run
from tweepy import Stream
from tweepy import OAuthHandler
from tweepy.streaming import StreamListener
import smaclient
import MySQLdb
import sys
from textblob import TextBlob

ckey = ''
csecret = ''
atoken = ''
asecret = ''
license_key = '


@route('/')
def hello():
    return '''
    </br></br></br></br></br></br>
    <h1 align="center">Gavin's Twitter Sentiment Analysis</h1>
    <p align="center">Enter a word into the search box below</p>
        <form action="/page2" method="post" align="center">
            Search: <input name="search" type="text" />
            <input value="Search" type="submit" />
        </form>
    '''


@route('/page2', method='POST')
def result():
    search = request.forms.get('search')
    result = analyze(search)
    return result


def analyze(subject):
    auth = OAuthHandler(ckey, csecret)
    auth.set_access_token(atoken, asecret)
    twitterStream = Stream(auth, listener())
    return twitterStream.filter(track=[subject])


class listener(StreamListener):
    i = 0

    def on_data(self, data):
        print data
        tweet = data.split(',"text":"')[1].split('","source')[0]
        print tweet
        db = MySQLdb.connect(
            host='localhost',
            user='root',
            passwd='',
            db='sentiment'
        )
        cursor = db.cursor()
        no = 2
        cursor.execute('INSERT INTO tweets (Tweet, no) VALUES (%s, %s)', (tweet, no))
        db.commit()
        positive = 0
        negative = 0
        self.i += 1
        if self.i > 5:
            cursor = db.cursor()
            cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM tweets")
            rows = cursor.fetchall()
            for eachRow in rows:
                tweet = eachRow[0]
                blob = TextBlob(tweet)
                blob.language = 'en'
                polarity = blob.sentiment.polarity
                if (polarity < - 0.10):
                    negative += 1
                elif (polarity > 0.10):
                    negative += 1

            cursor.execute('DELETE FROM tweets WHERE no = 2')
            db.commit()
            if positive > negative:
                return 'positive'
            else:
                return 'negative'
        sys.exit()


run(host='localhost', port=7000, debug=True)
```